# Is the phrase "Hello, my dear fellow" considered weird nowadays?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I was wondering if the **"Hello, my dear fellow"** salutation is considered weird nowadays.
A friend of mine (one British chap) once said it sounded "gay" =) I'd like to ask native speakers' opinion. Thanks!

PS: of course, the phrase is meant to be used in informal speech.

Comment: Not only weird but deliberately affected, like you're *trying* to sound like a Victorian Brit. I imagine steampunk cosplayers greeting each other this way, but no one else.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=PIZ5VMGcKpKLuATR-oCACw&ved=0CAkQ1S4#q=%22Hello,+my+dear+fellow%22&tbs=qdr:y

Comment: Use *fellow* in an adjectival sense, not a noun in itself: *fellow ELUers* ....

Comment: It is quaint, old-fashioned, Victorian, posh, archaicising, and a host of other things… but it is certainly not _gay_ in any sense of the word I'm familiar with. That's a very odd word to use to describe it. It's neither particularly jolly, particularly homosexual, or particularly idiotic or derisible.

Comment: To this native Brit it does sound effete as well as dated.

Answer (score 2):

I am an American from the Midwest, and although I think it sounds "cool," the use of the noun "fellow" does sound a bit "affected" "a bit dated" and gives the sense of "being light in the loafers." That being said, if the friend with whom you are using it with is a good one, then none of this matters.

Comment: Agreed with all of this, +1 (well, except I don't find the phrase "cool").

Comment: I guess it's the possibility that in the States we think all Brits "sound cool." British English has a melodic ring to the ears. But this is purely subjective.

Comment: Brother, I live in New York.

Comment: Ah, hence my use of the NP "the possibility" and adjective "subjective." Cheers!

Comment: "People don't talk that way any more" (c) National Treasure.
 
I do find this phrase nice also, as well as many others of that era... the era when English was way closer to my soul, figuratively speaking. but - who cares? =)

Comment: @PatrickT.Randolph "Cheers" to you too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most times when I hear the term *fellow*, I think of the chant/song that people sing (raucously) on special occasions, for example when a person has achieved something quite exceptional; someone's birthday or at wedding receptions.

> For he's a jolly good fellow, for he's a jolly good fellow
>   For he's a jolly good fellow (pause), and so say all of us
>   And so say all of us, and so say all of us
>   For he's a jolly good fellow, for he's a jolly good fellow
>   For he's a jolly good felloooooow (pause), and so say all of us!
>
> <sup><sub>[the note on the last *fellow* is especially prolonged]</sub></sup>
>   <sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_He%27s_a_Jolly_Good_Fellow#British_version)</sup>

With the exception of that celebratory song, and probably due to its association with Victorian and Edwardian Britain, the expression *good/jolly/dear fellow* will sound particularly ‘posh’ i.e. your friend's comment ‘*gay*’, and outdated to many British native speakers.

Comment: "Some Like it Hot" scene:
http://youtu.be/n8n-PDVYgu4?t=6s
=)

Comment: @Rossitten yep, pretty much that's how it should be sung, but without the final fireworks! (note the American version has the line *which nobody can deny*)  Good movie that one. :)